# How to make the home page of the web page dynamically adjust the page media?

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

I'm using page media to define the home page of the web page, but it can't be dynamically adjusted, it can only be adjusted before each rendering, which is very inconvenient

here is the css code：

```
.test-matter {
  page: matter;
}
@page matter{
  margin-top: 20mm;
  margin-right: 15mm;
  margin-bottom: 20mm;
  margin-left: 15mm;
}
```

But it only seems to apply the default page media settings , each side is margin 25mm

Comment: @page is used for printing. Are you trying to print your homepage ? or ? and what do you mean by ' dinamically ' ?

Comment: I want to make the page media configuration of the home page use a custom configuration instead of a preset configuration

Comment: What do you mean when saying '  page media of the homepage ' ?

Comment: My home page refers to the first page of the web page, which was originally defined by page:first, but I want to change it to a custom configuration

Answer (score -1):

You can use `JavaScript` for making this easier. If you use the `onresize="myFunction()"` your function will be called every time you change window size.Just add the following:

**JavScript**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   // Your code here
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body onresize="myFunction()">
    <!-- HTML here -->
</body>
```

You can use css in the function, to dynamically change it.